# Formulario php y javacript, como dejar la option marcada, (sesión )

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estoy usando php y me gustaría hacer que después de darle al input en el select se quede seleccionado la  ultima opción que marcó

con JavaScript he intentado esto

```js
function dejarSelected(){
     document.getElementById("Euro").setAttribute("selected","selected");
        alert("hola");
    }//Fin Función
```

```html
     <select name="inputMonU1" id="selectedIMon1">
             <option id="Pesetas" value="Pesetas">Pesetas</option>
             <option  id="Dolar" value="Dolar">Dolar</option>
             <option id="YenJapones" value="YenJapones">Yen Japones</option>
             <option id="Cruceiro" value="Cruceiro">Cruceiro</option>
             <option  id="Euro" value="Euro">Euro</option>
     </select>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="dejarSelected()"id="calcular" value="Calcular" />
```

Comment: ¿Envías el formulario por medio del post del mismo FORM o lo haces a través de AJAX?

Comment: mediante post  del mismo form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto que necesitas, lo tienes que hacer en el lado servidor, debido a que al momento de que envías el formulario, la página se recarga y los valores del JS se pierden.

Para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente.

En el archivo php, al cual envías los datos, crea una variable de sesión y le asignas el valor que venga del post del elemento SELECT

```
<?php

// Inicias la sesión
session_start();

//Asignas el valor a la variable de sesión del select
//Aquí cambias la opción POST o GET, según corresponda
$_SESSION["selectedOption"] = $_POST['inputMonU1'];

?>
```

Y por último, si existe el valor lo asignas

```
<script>
var valueSelected = '<?php echo $_SESSION['selectedOption']; ?>';
if(valueSelected !== ''){
document.getElementById("selectedIMon1").value = country;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias todo perfecto !

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien que quieres hacer, quieres hacer submit a no se sabe que pagina, es decir le haces un submit, de tu pagina a la misma pagina ? No se si te refieras al

```
$_SESSION['POST']  y el `$_SESSION['GET']`
```

No se bien porque necesitas sesiones, deberias explicar un como mas tu problema o si te sirve este link.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp 
no se si te sirva

Comment: Buenas, quería hacer " selectedIndex " pero como el form recargaba en la misma página, se hacia de 0 todo, por eso queria guardar de alguna forma esa opcion seleccionada, para que al usuario le aparezca su seleccion despeus de haberle dado al input